# How to draw dotted line in pdfBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using Pdfbox to draw some line on my document.
Code:

```
contentStream.drawLine(startX, startY, startX, endY);
```

The result is an straight line. I wonder Does the PdfBox can draw dotted line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the setLineDashPattern() call before doing your drawLine call:

```
public void setLineDashPattern(float[] pattern, float phase)
```

example:

```
setLineDashPattern (new float[]{3}, 0);
```

will configure a line pattern with 3 on, 3 off, 3 on, 3 off, etc

```
setLineDashPattern (new float[]{3,1}, 0);
```

will configure a line pattern with 3 on, 1 off, 3 on, etc

for more details on dash patterns, see [the PDF specification](http://www.verypdf.com/document/pdf-format-reference/pg_0218.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm newbie. :)